# iPhone simulator shows black screen when setting a custom UIViewController class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, ios-simulator

When creating a single view application in Xcode and dragging a `UIButton` in, for example, the button shows up when running the application in the iPhone simulator. However, when creating a new `UIViewController` class and setting that as the custom class of the view controller in the storyboard file, just a black screen is shown in the iPhone Simulator.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: posting some of your code would be helpful.

Comment: As I just created a new Xcode project, I haven't written any code at all. I'm creating an app in which this problem suddenly occurred, so I decided to just create a new Xcode project to see if that does actually work, which was not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet the Xcode template included the loadView method in your controller class. You need to delete that as you only override that method when you are creating your interface via code.

Comment: I do not recall having done that earlier, when it did actually work, but this did the job. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think in Xcode 4.3 the templates started include loadView if you do not "also create the nib" file when creating the controller class. I also don't recall needing to remove loadView when using Xcode 4.2.